# org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1 WriteValue method

Tags: c, api, glib, dbus, bluez

I am working with Bluez-5.43 and I'm using the dbus API .

When trying to write a value to a characteristic using the WriteValue method the following error appear:

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "WriteValue" with signature "ay" on interface "org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1" doesn't exist.
```

I'll be thankful if someone help me solving this issue :)

This is the code that causing this problem:

```
GVariant *char_value = g_variant_new_from_data(G_VARIANT_TYPE ("ay"), buffer, *buffer_len, TRUE, NULL, NULL);
if (char_value == NULL){
    printf("converting value error\n");
    return -1;
}
else{
    printf("converting value succeed\n");
    g_dbus_proxy_call_sync (char_write_proxy, "WriteValue", g_variant_new ("(@ay)", char_value), G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE, -1, NULL, &error);
    printf("lign 154\n");
    if (error != NULL){
        printf("write failed:    %s\n", error->message);
        return -1;
    }
    else
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your code that creates this problem?

Comment: You should post that in your post

Answer (score 2):

WriteValue() signature is actually "aya{sv}", in other words you need a (typically empty) dictionary as a second argument.

The docs are pretty good: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt

There are multiple ways to build a dictionary, I prefer a Variantbuilder. Something like this:

```
GVariantBuilder builder;
g_variant_builder_init (&builder, G_VARIANT_TYPE("a{sv}"));
write_value_argument = g_variant_new ("(@aya{sv})", char_value, &builder);
```

Comment: thank you for the response :) can you please help me how to pass those arguments when invoking WriteValue method using g_dbus_proxy_call_sync

Comment: I've added an _untested_ example -- I think that's correct but these can be tricky... https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/gvariant-format-strings.html is a good resource when trying to get that right -- it also explains the "builder as g_variant_new() argument" trick.

Comment: Really useful answer for me as well. I tested your example and it works. @JussiKukkonen